# Firestore - Type 'Query<T>' is missing the following properties from type 'CollectionReference<T>': id, path, parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

i'm trying to refactor some firebase (V9) code from JS to TS but I'm having some issues with my useCollection hook.

I get error on this part

```
  if (q) {
      ref = query(ref, where(...q), limit(l)) 
    }
```

**on ref**
Type 'Query' is missing the following properties from type 'CollectionReference': id, path, parentts(2739)

and

**on ...q**
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
Type 'Query<T[]>' is not an array type.ts(2461)

I'm really struggling to understand where to go from here :/

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase/fbconfig";

// firebase
import { collection, CollectionReference, DocumentData, limit, onSnapshot, Query, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

// c = collection, q = query, l = limit, o = orderBy


export const useCollection = <T = DocumentData>(c: string, _q: Query<T[]>, l: number) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<DocumentData[]>([]);

  // setup query
  const q = useRef(_q).current

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c) as CollectionReference<T>

    if (q) {
      ref = query(ref, where(...q), limit(l)) 
    }

    const unsub =  onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      let results: DocumentData[] = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        results.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
      setDocuments(results)
    });

    // cleanup func
    return () => unsub()

  }, [c, q, l]);

  return { documents }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!